# How to create a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a table in SQL Server, and I want to create a stored procedure to insert data for the table (`UserInformation`).

I am new to this, so please give me the info how to create that stored procedure.

Comment: Open your favourate browser and search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create Stored Procedure

```
Create procedure  MyProcedure 
(@id  varchar(20),@search varchar(20) ) -- these are the parameters to this procedure
as

begin

    select * from yourTable where ID=@id

end
```

or ( Without Parameters )

```
Create procedure  MyProcedure   
as

begin

    select * from yourTable where ID=10

end
```

calling a stored Procedure with Entity Framework

```
// tbl_CompMgmt is a class which look exctly like the result returned 
var mgtList = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<tbl_CompMgmt>("exec GetSortedManagement @Companay_ID=" + compID).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Arun, Please help me as how to call stored procedure by asp.net, I have created a select stored procedure, now how to call it

Comment: Please refer this page  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748619/ADO-NET-How-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-output

Comment: if you have trouble just post here